# how can I redirect a domain to secure SSL?

Tags: php

I have a domain and want it to redirect to secure ssl with https. how can I do it? because sometimes it goes to http domain, not https domain.

Comment: Assuming you're using it for your web server, you'll want to look at Apache rewrite rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Apache you can use this code lines in .htaccess file;

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```